# WCF Contract first: complexType has already been declared

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl, svcutil.exe, design-by-contract

I am using svcutil.exe to generate a service endpoint based on a contract from an external source.

It seems to work as intended, but the service is not able to expose an endpoint to others.

Specifically, when I try to GET the WSDL for the service, an exception is thrown with the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to
>   a WSDL export extension:
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior 
>   contract:
>   http://tempuri.org/xml/wsdl/soap11/DistributionService/1/port:DistributionReceiverWebServicePort
>   ----> System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaException: The complexType 'http://tempuri.org/xml/wsdl/soap11/DistributionService/1/types:FejlType'
>   has already been declared.

But - the type `FejlType` type is only declared once and is a very simple class:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/xml/wsdl/soap11/DistributionService/1/types")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name = "FejlType", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/xml/wsdl/soap11/DistributionService/1/types")]
public class FejlType : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
{
    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;
    private string FejlKodeField;
    private string FejlTekstField;

    public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
    {
        get {return this.extensionDataField;}
        set {this.extensionDataField = value;}
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string FejlKode
    {
        get {return this.FejlKodeField;}
        set {this.FejlKodeField = value;}
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string FejlTekst
    {
        get {return this.FejlTekstField;}
        set {this.FejlTekstField = value;}
    }
}
```

I am totally in the dark here - why does WCF complain about this when exporting the WSDL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem.

FYI: the WSDL originates from KOMBIT (a Danish Government IT-thingy) and the WSDL is a part of their data hub (Serviceplatformen)

I discovered that the service classes generated by svcutil.exe had the type `FejlType` implemented twice - both as partial classes, btw. One of them had a specific .net namespace prefix and the other did not have its own prefix. What was causing the problem was an `XmlTypeAttribute` on the types - each of them exposing the same xml namespace. So even though the service classes did compile, they exposed the same xml type specification - causing the exception I reported here.